# Add 'sep=' line to the csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

The problem is, I want to copy data from .csv file, but excel automatically separates it into columns by comma, I need to separate it by ";".Can I edit csv file using vba code to add 'sep=' at the beginning?

Comment: Do a proper import of the CSV and use the Import Text Wizard. See the note in [Import or export text (.txt or .csv) files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba). This way you can choose the seperator and change it to  `;`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Excel anyway separates data by commas regardless I either use Open or OpenText. The thoughts I had is to convert somehow .csv file into .txt and then use Text Wizard or find the way to edit .csv file by adding 'sep=;' at the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution worked for me is to use filesystem object to read csv file and copy it into temporary file with 'sep=' at the first line.
Here is the code:

```
Function readCsvF(delim as String, fPath as String) As String
    Dim sourceFile As Object, objFSO as Object, newTempFile as Object, _
    line as String, newName as String
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set sourceFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fPath)
    newName = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(fPath) & "\tempCSVfile.csv"
    Set newTempFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(newName, True)
    newTempFile.Writeline("sep=" & delim)
    While Not sourceFile.AtEndOfStream
        line = sourceFile.Readline
        newTempFile.Writeline (line)
    Wend
    sourceFile.Close
    newTempFile.Close
    readCsvF = newName
End Function
```

So what this function does is basically creates new file in which writes first line `sep=*'your specified delimiter'*` and then copies data from original csv file line by line. This function takes two string parameters: `delim` is delimiter you want to use and `fPath` is a path to the csv file, - and returns a path to the new file, so you can open it as workbook and do whatever manipulation you want with it.

Hopefully this will help someone, I really struggled to find the solution, maybe there was any better way, idk.

Answer (score 1):

Excel/VBA ignores the separator option if the file has the .csv extension. You have to rename it to set the delimiter. Check out my [VBA CSV parser](https://pchemguy.github.io/CSVParser/) project.